# Deciding factors for publishing in a good journal

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

While going through the literature survey for my project, I found that some papers have been published in reputed journals while some are not. But the study area, data used are very much similar in both cases. Also, the method followed is similar.

So my question is, based on the above context, what factors are responsible for research work to get accepted in a good journal?

*PS - The papers are related to the earth science field.*

Comment: Of course, to be published in Journal X, you need to submit to Journal X. Good papers are likely to be published in the journal they are first submitted to.

Comment: In your case, the *first* study, assuming it is solid work, will appear in a good journal.  Any derivative works, and presumably *less interesting* works will probably appear in lower ranking journals.  There are many factors that determine whether paper-X appears in journal-Y.  You can search this forum to check what makes a good article.